# Check Constraint in Django F Expression

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model with a field defined:

`contacts = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)`

...
Further down I am trying to do a decrement on the field using `F()` an expression:

`self.contacts = models.F("contacts") - quantity`

How do I check `contacts - quantity` does not go negative without introducing a race condition?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of defining such a constraint, but you could do the check in a transaction (`@transaction.atomic`). There is also [this library](https://code.google.com/p/django-check-constraints/wiki/Features), but it is really old.

Comment: @Ivan, Thanks for that. If I used the `@transaction.atomic` decorator then I wouldn't really need to use the `F()` expression, right?

Comment: You will have already retrieved everything, so no.

Comment: Also, [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) can be used as a context manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to avoid race conditions. `F()` objects are only a first step in this.

The first thing you'd want to do in your transaction is to acquire a lock on the row you're changing. This prevents that you read a value that is outdated by the time you write to the database. This can be done with an update of the row, that will lock the row from further updates until the transaction is committed or rolled back:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    obj.contacts = F('contacts') - quantity
```

When you have the lock, and done the update, check if data integrity is still intact (i.e. the number of contacts isn't lower than 0). If it is, continue, otherwise, rollback the transaction by raising an exception:

```
obj.refresh_from_db()
if obj.contacts < 0:
    raise ValueError("Capacity exceeded")
```

If there are enough contacts left, you'll exit the `atomic()` block at this point, the transaction is committed, and other requests can acquire the lock and try to update the value. If there aren't enough contacts, the transaction is rolled back, and other requests will never have known the value has changed, as they've been waiting to get the lock.

Now, to put it all together:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import F

def update_contacts(obj, quantity):
    with transaction.atomic():
        obj.contacts = F('contacts') - quantity
        obj.save()
        obj.refresh_from_db()
        if obj.contacts < 0:
            raise ValueError("Not enough contacts.")
```

(Note: `obj.refresh_from_db()` requires 1.8, otherwise just use `MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)`.)

Comment: Don't you hit the db at least 3 times this way? You actually need only two - to retrieve, and to save if all checks are OK.

Comment: I assume you also retrieve the `obj`?

Comment: If 2 requests simultaneously retrieve the object before the other one updates it and gets the lock, they can both individually pass the check. When you update the object in both requests, the number of contacts can drop below 0. If you want to avoid all race conditions, you need at least 3 database hits.

Comment: @knbk, Sorry it took so long. I just got back to work :D